# Webservices: [failed to localize] The endpointInterface class Calculator could not be found()

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, ibm-was

I created a webservice called calculator, an interface, an implementation class, and annotated it, and I was trying to create the service and the WSDL. Then I get the following Error. Not sure if it's a facet error or an error in the version of JAXWS from WAS 8.0? Tried to resolve it but couldn't find resources on the web as well.
    ** Here's the CODE**

```
//Interface: 

package com.pp;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface Calculator {
    @WebMethod
    public int add(int var1, int var2);

}

//Implementation Class: 
package com.pp;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface=" com.pp.Calculator")
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

    @Override
    public int add(int var1, int var2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return var1+var2;
    }

}
```

**ERROR:**

```
 Errors occurred during wsgen.
      Errors occurred during wsgen.
      error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported

      Note:     ap round: 1
    Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
    see stacktrace below for more information.
    com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: [failed to localize] The endpointInterface class  com.pp.Calculator could not be found()
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.onError(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.getEndpointInterfaceDecl(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalImplementation(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.shouldProcessWebService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitClassDeclaration(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.ClassDeclarationImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.buildModel(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jdk6.jws22.command.WsGenCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.command.WsGenCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
```